# Mint nft Collection from 0 to 9999

Tags: linux-mint, nft

i created my collection and the collection starts from 0 to 9999 but when i mint it mints from number 1 not 0

example of my json file

````
  {
    "name": " #0",
    "description": "NFT TEST",
    "image": "ipfs://NewUriToReplace/0.png",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "Background",
        "value": "Orange"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Eyeball",
        "value": "Red"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Eye color",
        "value": "Yellow"
      }
   ],
    "dna": "51dde0558661708099f7575da644987b7b746792",
    "edition": 0,
    "external_url": "https://evtest.com",
    "date": 1650569986394,
    "compiler": "EV Compiler"
  },```
````

Answer (score 0):

So that the creation of the metadata and images of the NFTs does not start at 0 to 9999, I modified the "main.js" file so that it starts from 1 to 10000. Just look for this file in the folder that makes it possible to create the NFTs, open it and you have to look for a section of the code that is the following:

```
const startCreating = async () => {
  let layerConfigIndex = 0;
  let editionCount = 1;
  let failedCount = 0;
  let abstractedIndexes = [];
  for (
    let i = network == NETWORK.sol ? 0 : 0;
    i <= layerConfigurations[layerConfigurations.length - 1].growEditionSizeTo;
    i++
  ) {
    abstractedIndexes.push(i);
  }
```

Now let the part where "let i = network == NETWORK.sol ? 0 : 0;" is replace the second 0 with a 1. This is how the code should look.

```
const startCreating = async () => {
  let layerConfigIndex = 0;
  let editionCount = 1;
  let failedCount = 0;
  let abstractedIndexes = [];
  for (
    let i = network == NETWORK.sol ? 0 : 1;
    i <= layerConfigurations[layerConfigurations.length - 1].growEditionSizeTo;
    i++
  ) {
    abstractedIndexes.push(i);
  }
```

In this way the creation of the NFTs will start at 1 and end at 10,000.